# Assigning part of a command output to a variable (bash)

Tags: bash

I have a script which produces the following output:

```
[RESPONSE]  code = 211  description = Domain name not available queuetime = 0   runtime = 0.009
```

I need to assign only the `code = 211` part to a variable. How will I do that?

Comment: You mean store `code = 211` in a variable say `var`

Comment: Also is the output format constant? Also what efforts so far?

Comment: Hi. No I do not need to store the output. The output is a result of domain check. code=211 means the domain is not available. Yes the code changes when the domain becomes available to code=210. Oh the format is yes constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to store `code = 211` to a variable say `var` do this :

```
$ var="$(./your_script | sed -E 's/.*(code = [[:digit:]]+).*/\1/')"
$ echo "$var"
code = 211
```

Instead, if you wish to assign 211 to `code` given the result of the script:

```
$ eval "$(./your_script | sed -E 's/.*(code = [[:digit:]]+).*/\1/;s/ //g')"
$ echo "$code"
211
```

**Notes**

- `s/.*(code = [[:digit:]]+).*/` retains the `code = number` part of the result
- `s/ //g` deletes the spaces around `=` so that `code=number` is passed to `eval`

Comment: sjsam, I received this error. -bash-3.2$ ./check.sh
sed: invalid option -- E
Usage: sed [OPTION]... {script-only-if-no-other-script} [input-file]...

Comment: @turnic : What platform are you on? You may replace `-E` with `-r` and lemme know the result'

Comment: @turnic If I'm not mistaken you're running an infinite while loop? Am I right?

Comment: It should be `if [ "$code" -eq "210" ] then`. The hint is `-eq` for comparing integers and `=` is for strings, sarcastic it might seem

Comment: @turnic : If possible paste your script in [\[ pastebin \]](http://pastebin.com/) and gimme the link. Looks a bit obscure at the moment.

Comment: I have put the error suppression inside quotes, Check [\[ this \]](http://pastebin.com/raw/6VrimYig) and please delete the comments except the relevant ones.

Comment: @turnic Also could you update me what is the output of `/home/turnic/mreg/mreg checkdomain domain=netfair.de`. I mean just that command alone

Comment: @turnic  Is the output of `/home/turnic/mreg/mreg checkdomain domain=netfair.de` a one line output?

Comment: @turnic : The link is not working. :( It's taking too long. Why don't you paste the output in pastebin and send me the link

Comment: So a single instance of `mreg` will give you so many reponses. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

```
#Assuming there is space between [response] and code.Seems there is from your example.

var=$(./yourScript.sh |awk '{print $2,$3,$4}')

echo $var
code = 211
```

Comment: A alternative may be `eval "$(./script|awk '{printf "%s=%s",$2,$4}')"`

Comment: This does assume that output has a fixed format. If that is not the case, this will not work. You may use awk `sub` to work around. nbd though.